# `expo start` in development stuck at "Tunnel Connected", QR code is unusable

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I'm currently running a detached expo project in development mode. Whenever I run `expo start` or `npm start` in the terminal I get the following logs:

```
$ expo start                                                                                                                                                                      
Starting project at /Users/johncd/workspace
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
Tunnel ready.
Your native app is running at expb675c828acbb437095bc6218883f56bb://192.168.1.12:19000
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
```

***The expected results*** would include a QR code after these logs, but there is none.

When I visit the DevTools at localhost:90002 I see the metro bundler is running on LAN and a QR code is available. However, when I scan this QR code, it results in an error reading ***"No usable data found".***

[image: No usable data found when scanning QR code]

- ***I've tried*** checking for a Firewall (System preferences > Privacy > Firewall) but it appears to be turned off.
- I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing `expo-cli` as well as the project and running `expo start` again but to no avail.
- I've tried using `npm start` and `yarn start`. I have also tried running the project on a tunnel.
- I created a test project using `expo init test-project` and successfully ran it using `expo start`, so it seems this issue is only occurring on this project.
- I also tried running `expo start --clear` to clear the cache.

None of these have worked.

Any help is appreciated!

Versions:

```
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^5.0.1",
    "expokit": "^33.0.4",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.4.2",]
```

Running on OSX

Comment: Seems like it would be nice if you would accept an answer. For me the one from iosdev1111 was best. It's second in the list right now.

Answer (score 13):

You need to install expo client app first from the appstore, then the qr will be readable.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install Expo Go application from app store.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see anywhere a mention of what platform you're trying to use (iOS or Android) but at least with iOS I can tell you that QR codes in Expo don't really work correctly anymore. I believe Apple prevented the Expo team from being allowed to serve the bundle through the Expo app anymore. What this means for you is that the workflow you should expect is to connect your phone to the device physically using a cable and serve the bundle through USB. You can also use an emulator and move to the device when it's convenient.